# How should I Restore My Local storage data when I migrate from UWP to WinUI UnPackaged app MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui, winui-3

so I have migrated my Xamarin app to MAUI. that means from UWP to WinUI in Windows.
I was using Windows.Storage API Which works fine in Packagedapps (MSIX). However, shipping the app outside of the MS Store in that format is quite annoying (specifically the signing and sideloading.) Every user has to first trust my self-signed certificate and then install the app.

I would like to publish the app as an unpackaged version, but the Windows.Storage API is not supported in unpackaged apps due to package identity missing. So I can change it to System.IO.File

But already many users are using our app. So there might me data loss when I shift from windows.storage to system.IO.FIle . Is there any way I Can restore those old data stored using  Windows.Storage?

As location path of windows.Storage and System.IO.File is different. I have no idea how to get back the information stored using windows.Storage as it is important data. Please suggests any ideal solution for this.

Comment: Any app can still use `Windows.Storage` API but obviously it won't be able to use methods related to packaging (like `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo`, `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package`, `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`, etc.). From an unpackage app you can get the equivalent of `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`, with `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Packages", MyOldPackageFamilyName, "LocalState")` if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @SimonMourier thankyou for your comment .can you please help me with what should I replace  MyOldPackageFamilyName

Comment: Should be `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo.Current.PackageFamilyName` from your packaged/UWP version.

Answer (score 0):

Any Windows app can still use [Windows.Storage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage) (`StorageFolder`, `StorageFile`, etc.) but obviously, if it's not packaged, it won't be able to use methods related to packaging (like [Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinfo.current), [Windows.ApplicationModel.Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.current), [ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder), etc.).

So, from an unpackaged app that was previously packaged, you can keep most of your `Windows.Storage` API based code. The equivalent of

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
```

can be replaced by something like

```
Path.Combine(       
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData,
    "Packages",
    myOldPackageFamilyName,
    "LocalState")
```

with `myOldPackageFamilyName` being the value of  `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo.Current.PackageFamilyName` from the packaged version.